# Is there a way for a blazor hosted Webassembly app to use an existing functional Identity Server 4 only for the purpose of authentication?

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

So here's how it goes:
I have a fully functional Blazor WebAssembly asp.net core Hosted app and a functional Identity server both on different ports.
I want to use the Identity server for authentication and logging in...etc. and I'm having trouble with making the blazor app depend on the Identity server for authentication...
how do I tell it to get/verify the tokens from the server before executing the actions in the controllers?
I think what makes my case a bit different is that I use the Server project in place of the web api instead of using two separate client and web api projects...
Thanks.

Comment: You have to declare the server and client as clients in ID4 and declare a scope for the controllers. When the client authenticates it should request the scope for the controllers. When I did this all 3 where on separate ports though. Your WASM client does not need to be hosted. If you update the client you have to publish the server with your arrangement.

Comment: @BrianParker How do I go on about doing that (in terms of code) are there any Tutorials/docs? and to be extra extra clear my company wants to use Identity Server just for Single Sign On purposes, not for protecting REST APIs... and this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) here by microsoft only shows you how to secure it using an instance of ID4, what I'm looking for is more like using a single login for more than one packages... Thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/

Comment: Thanks mate! not sure how I've missed it, but I assume this [link](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/7_blazor/) seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks again @BrianParker

Comment: Let me know if you have issues I have done this with ID4 but the docs for ID4 where available then...